# Facebook Connect and Codeigniter - HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

i'm struggling really hard to implement Facebook connect into my codeigniter application - I have one issue right now. After downloading the PHP SDK from here: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/ I copied the /src files into my CI libraries (as everyone do : )).

Now I want to authenticate my users using this method:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

My controller is here (I think the problem is at the end, but pasted full file, cause i'm not sure):

```
<?php

class Fb25 extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
            $app_id     = "MY APP ID";
    $app_secret = "MY SECRET KEY";
    $site_url   = "http://devlocalhost.com/";

$this->load->library('facebook',array('appId' => $app_id, 'secret' => $app_secret));

    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
    $data['user'] = $user;

if($user){

    $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');    
    $user_profile = $data['user_profile'];

} else{

    $user = NULL;

}       

if($user){
// Get logout URL
$data['logoutUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
    'next'  => 'http://devlocalhost.com/', // URL to which to redirect the user after logging out
    ));
}else{
// Get login URL
    $data['loginUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'     => 'email', // Permissions to request from the user
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://devlocalhost.com/fb25/good', // URL to redirect the user to once the login/authorization process is complete.
    ));
}

if($user){


// Save your method calls into an array
$data['queries'] = array(
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/home?limit=50'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/friends'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/photos?limit=6'),
    );

// POST your queries to the batch endpoint on the graph.
    $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');


//Return values are indexed in order of the original array, content is in ['body'] as a JSON
//string. Decode for use as a PHP array.
$data['user_info']      = json_decode($batchResponse[0]['body'], TRUE);
$data['feed']           = json_decode($batchResponse[1]['body'], TRUE);
$data['friends_list']   = json_decode($batchResponse[2]['body'], TRUE);
$data['photos']         = json_decode($batchResponse[3]['body'], TRUE);


    }
    echo 'user_info: '.$data['user_info'];
    print_r($data);

    $this->load->view('fb25_view', $data);
}

public function good(){

$app_id     = "MY APP ID";
    $app_secret = "MY SECRET KEY";
    $site_url   = "http://devlocalhost.com/";


echo '<br/><br/>SESJA:<br/>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '<br/><br/>GET:<br/>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '<br/><br/>REQUEST:<br/>';
print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo '<br/><br/>najs<br/><br/>';




   session_start();

  $code = $_GET["code"];

  //@@@@@@IMO PROBLEM IS SOMEWHERE HERE: 


 $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;


 $response = file_get_contents($token_url);

 $params = null;
 parse_str($response, $params);

 $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
   . $params['access_token'];

 $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
 echo("Hello " . $user->name);



}
}
?>
```

My problem is: I'm pressing the login button and gets into facebook to authenticate myself, clicking "go to app" and want to go back into my website - it says:

```
Message: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token? client_id=487560264592073&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdevlocalhost.com%2F&client_secret=mysecretcode&code=AQAgnmNWwDub9yaRB6Vf73gg8Xvwo8KhIM077lB67_bu1Z3rAvyk3Ckl54qK7hh9o3VkG0rFIBTfRXwtrSBFVWEpqYfm1o7e5CQg3jVctq-EE1ZxWrgWrfesLpQ2oF3wlmEMb5o6ORobGmibT06kqe5f2N0ch4kSYBJ4SiTcdV-612fGOJHGcipeyU_GJJ0Jvsg) 

[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

**UPDATE**

Look here, please:

I added function into your controller:

```
public function link(){
$fb_usr = $this->fb_connect->user;
 $firstname = $fb_usr['first_name']; 

$my_url="http://devlocal.pl";
echo 'user_id';


 $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=mysecretcode&code=" . $_GET['code'];

    redirect($token_url);
```

}

To get my access token - without access token I can't get my username..
I made your loginbyfacebook function redirecting into link function. And it doesn't show the fb username.

When I'm redirecting to my token_url It shows:

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "Error validating verification code.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 100
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a whitespace between the `access_token?` and `client_id=` in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

```
1.Put the facebook php sdk in library folder
2.create facebook config with app detail
3.Inherit facebook class in fb_connect
4.add these function in controller then it will work like charm.
```

fb_connect.php

```
<?php
include(APPPATH.'libraries/facebook/facebook.php');

class Fb_connect extends Facebook{

    //declare public variables
    public  $user       = NULL;
    public  $user_id    = FALSE; 
    public $fb          = FALSE;
    public $fbSession   = FALSE;
    public $appkey      = 0;

    //constructor method.
    public function __construct()
    {
               $CI = & get_instance();
                $CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
                $config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
                parent::__construct($config);                   
                $this->user_id = $this->getUser(); // New code

                $me = null;
                if ($this->user_id) {
                    try {
                        $me = $this->api('/me');
                        $this->user = $me;
                        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                            error_log($e);
                        }
        }
    } 

} // end class
```

Controller function

```
function loginByFacebook(){
        $this->load->library('fb_connect');      
$param = array(
             'scope' =>'email,user_location,user_birthday,offline_access',
                'redirect_uri' => base_url()
            );
        redirect($this->fb_connect->getLoginUrl($param));


}

function facebook() {   

        if (!$this->fb_connect->user_id) {      

        } else {        
            $fb_uid = $this->fb_connect->user_id;
            $fb_usr = $this->fb_connect->user;  
            $firstname = $fb_usr['first_name'];
                    }
         }
```

In this way

```
$fb_usr = $this->fb_connect->user;
 $firstname = $fb_usr['first_name'];
```

Comment: You mean, inherit base_facebook in facebook and facebook in fb_connect? What functions should be in fb connect?

Comment: and when I have config file with my facebook keys, where should I use these variables?

Comment: Yes you are right about the class hierarchy .....and config file is used in fb_connect. I have placed the fb_connect in the answer.

Comment: It's all good - it redirects me into authentication facebook dialog I accept and then it redirects me into  [code]http://devlocal.pl/?state=cbf63f64c1fc01daf756d713f888fbc2&code=AQCMnjP9ky3h4Bbyhj0oaeQ_-sh-5pqJj65c50toXxs_nxl-Bd8_9W3XTcm6Ivo618e4pwR24NozA-68vTFpyS8a4l3iFT8S71nWL8XlsSaPjMjxi98Lofks46z5LkfUBj9jJ6gzu4RIGVQkTQO1Ai6zlLmFCpgC85kUYzWnRl2TQ2LevURk0VGLAVEuT1UQ3HI#_=_ - what should I do then?

Comment: Means you are logged into using facebook, Now fetch the user detail from facebook and store that user detail in session and make the user access the site using facebook connect.

Comment: no i'm not, I should get my user id, etc - which I havent, this site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ tells that I should get access_token - and I didn't get it.

Comment: I should use code from gotten URL to push one more request to facebook - As i see : ]

Comment: Fetch the values in this way $fb_usr = $this->fb_connect->user; 
$firstname = $fb_usr['first_name'];

Comment: Take a look at my first post update, please - problem explained.